# Button redirecting to the grid page

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I have a custom module 'banner' and in which I have added a button in its second tab(only two tabs for the module). when click on that button, it is submitting my banner automatically and then go to the grid page(i e it acts as just another save button). But the function of this button is to add an uploading image field.ie whenever the button is clicked, it should add an image form field to my tab file. This is my tab file.

```
<?php
class Karaokeshop_Banner_Block_Adminhtml_Banner_Edit_Tab_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('banner_image', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('banner')->__('Banner Image')));
        //declaring a new custom form field and adding
        $fieldset->addType('add_button', 'Karaokeshop_Banner_Block_Adminhtml_Banner_Edit_Tab_Field_Custom'); 
        $fieldset->addField('banner_img_add_button', 'add_button', array(
            'title' => Mage::helper('banner')->__('Add Banner Image'),
            'id' => 'add_banner_img_button',
            'class' => 'scalable save',
            'style' => '',
            'onclick' => 'banner.add(this)',
            'type' => 'button',                    
        ));

         return parent::_prepareForm();                                                    
    }  

}
```

this is my button defining file

```
<?php
class Karaokeshop_Banner_Block_Adminhtml_Banner_Edit_Tab_Field_Custom extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
{
public function __construct($attributes=array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
public function getElementHtml()
{              
    $value = $this->getTitle();
    $onclick=$this->getOnclick();
    $class=$this->getClass();
    $id=$this->getId();
    $style=$this->getStyle();
    $type=$this->getType();
    $html='<button id="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'" onclick="'.$onclick.'" type="'.$type.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.' </button>';
    $html .= '<p id="' . $this->getHtmlId() . '"'. $this->serialize($this->getHtmlAttributes()) .'>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[

                var banner =  
                {                                                       
                        add : function(obj) 
                        {                                    

                        },

                };
            //]]>
            </script>
        </p>';
return $html;
}
}
```

what should i do to change my button to an add button? what should I do to avoid this submitting functionality of the button. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: use phtml and set custom function.this is not good way to program like you have done for button.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman thanks for the reply. what is the proper way to add an add_button to my second tab?

Comment: what are you trying to do in second tab ? are you saving something or something else ?

Comment: are you  saying to use a _construct() function in my tab file?

Comment: please put your tab code too in question.

Comment: second tab is using to upload images. but i need to display this button initially. when click on this button, i need to provide functionality for uploading an image through the tab. you got my point?every time we click the button, image adding functionality should provide, just like when we set custom options for a product.when we click on add option button there, it will provide a functionality for add an option and so on. i want to impliment exact same function here

Comment: i have provided my second tab defining file. did you mention tabs.phtml?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44128/discussion-between-mahmood-rehman-and-rajeevktomy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to call your phtml from block like this :

```
class My_Moudles_Block_Adminhtml_Image_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
   public function __construct()
  {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('modules/imageupload.phtml');
        $this->setFormAction(Mage::getUrl('*/*/imageupload'));


  }
```

then create file in `adminhtml/default/default/template/yourmodule/imageupload.phtml` and put this code there.

```
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
    <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend"><?php echo $this->__('General')?></h4>
    <div class="form-buttons"></div>
</div>
<form id="imageform" method="post" action="<? echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>">
    <div id="rules_form" class="fieldset ">
    <div class="hor-scroll">

                        <table cellspacing="0" class="form-list">
            <tbody>
          <tr>
    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Add Image')?></td>
    <td class="grid tier" colspan="10">
    <table cellspacing="0" id="chain_tiers" class="chain border" style=" width:465px; ">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headings">

                <th><?php echo $this->__('Image')?></th>
                <th class="last"><?php echo $this->__('Action')?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="template no-display" id="email_chain_add_template">

                <td class="nobr">
                    <input type="file" id="chain_Image" value="0" name="imageg" class="requried-entry input-text">
                </td>

                <td class="last"><input type="hidden" value="" disabled="no-template" class="delete" name="email_chain[__index__][delete]"><button onclick="emailsControl.deleteItem(event);return false" class="scalable delete icon-btn delete-product-option" title="Delete Image"><span><?php echo $this->__('Delete')?></span></button></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="a-right" colspan="6">
                    <button style="" onclick="emailsControl.addItem()" class="scalable add" type="button" title="Add email" id="id"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add Image')?></span></span></span></button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody id="email_chain_container">
                <tr>
                <td class="nobr">
                    <input type="file" id="chain_Image" value="" name="Image[]" class="input-text">
                </td>
                <td class="last"><input type="hidden" value="" class="delete" name="email_chain[delete][]"><button onclick="emailsControl.deleteItem(event);return false" class="scalable delete icon-btn delete-product-option" title="Delete Image"><span><?php echo $this->__('Delete')?></span></button></td>
            </tr>
              </tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
//&lt;![Cchain[

    var emailsControl = {
            itemsCount : 0,
            deleteButton : false,
            addItem : function () {
            var chain = {};
            chain.TEMPLATE_ID = 0;
            chain.index = this.itemsCount++;
            if (arguments.length == 1) {
            chain.TEMPLATE_ID = arguments[0];
            }
            var s = '<tr>' + $('email_chain_add_template').innerHTML.replace(/__index__/g, '#{index}').replace(/\sdisabled="?no-template"?/g, ' ').replace(/disabled/g, ' ').replace(/="'([^']*)'"/g, '="$1"') + '</tr>';
            var template = new Template(s); 

            Element.insert($('email_chain_container'), {'bottom': template.evaluate(chain)});
            $('chain_row_'+chain.index+'_TEMPLATE').value   = chain.TEMPLATE_ID;
            maxItemsCount++;

        },

        deleteItem : function(event) {
            var tr = Event.findElement(event, 'tr');
            if (tr) {
                jQuery(tr).remove();
            }
        }
    }
    var maxItemsCount = 2;
//]]&gt;
</script>
</td>
</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
            </div></form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Hopes this will solve your issue.
For edit you can do it like this :

```
<tbody id="email_chain_container">
            <?php  foreach($images as $row){ ?><tr>
   <td class="nobr">
                   your image code
                </td></tr>
```

Comment: this is not working. I have added your code in my tab file and also created the phtml file. but now my image tab(second tab) is empty now. not displaying any fields

Comment: firebug for possible errors.check may be some html missing that can casue empty otherwise remove cache and check again.

Comment: i have checked html code.it is correct and i have also cleared the cache and tried. but still nothing displays

Comment: remove all code from phtml and display just "working" and check whether it works or not ?

Comment: yes. now it is working perfectly. thanks a lot. you are brilliant. need to correct saveaction() now according to this

Comment: what should i do, if i need to display the currently uploaded images in the tab, when we are going to edit the images again?

Comment: then you should fetch image using foreach loop and display this in second image file

Comment: i also edit my answer for edit.Check that also .Will help you

Comment: what should i use to upload these images in save action? is that if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))) {}

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)`; you will get what you want

Comment: where should i display in order to see output? i have tried in grid page. it shows nothing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44134/discussion-between-mahmood-rehman-and-rajeevktomy)